# How can I replace apostrophes while uploading a csv file?

Tags: php, str-replace, apostrophe

I'm having trouble replacing apostrophes while uploading a csv file with a bunch of different descriptions.

Right now I have

```
$remarks = str_replace("'", "&#146;", $data[28]);
```

This gives me an error starting with the first apostrophe that shows up in my file. That first phrase where the apostrophe appears ends in "'s". If I change it to

```
$remarks = str_replace("'s", "&#146;", $data[28]);
```

it will go past that first problem and get to the next problem ('t).

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to php, and I'm sure this must be a simple solution...

Comment: What's the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map($data, function($a) { return(str_replace($a, "'", "&#146;")) });
```

should walk all elements of the array and replace all quotes for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to re-invent the wheel. It looks like you're trying to parse the csv yourself. If you are stop it. You should be using [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and you won't have to worry about escaping anything.

After that, you'll probably want to look into [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
preg_replace( "#'\w?#g", '', $data[$index] );
```